# text code before image but still next to eachtoghter how?

Tags: html, css

So I have looked everywhere couldn't find the answer.

Layout of the HTML code:

```
<div class="some_text"> text </div>
<img>
```

How you see it on the web:

```
text---images
```

Can this be done in css? Also the text and the image can't be swapped becuase on smaller screens the text neet te appear before the image.

Comment: i dont understand with the story you talking about, add some code or maybe a picture for further explanation

Comment: Seriously, how do you expect us to help you with this garbage information?

Comment: sorry for that i will try my best to improve

Comment: Pharagraph (`<p>`) is defaultly set as `display: block` so image is under the text. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/e7fx0p4k/ . If it acts differently, you have applied your own styles on it.

Comment: But what if i use a div? or does the div also need to contain the images?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .float-left{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px;
  width:30%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .float-left{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px;
}
</style>
<p class="float-left">text</p>
<img src="" style="width:150px;height: 150px;" alt="image">
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the text is to long. The solution on this is using <br> so the text doesn't get to long.

Comment: Please make this a good answer and explain a bit more. What's done here? Why does this answer the original question?